# How to find package name to uninstall a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg, uninstall

I have uninstalled my VirtualBox using `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-5.2` and the operation was successfull. But when run the command `apt-cache pkgnames virtualbox` it shows following result.

[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGIMn.png)

So i run `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` but it shows `Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed`. How can iremove those packages?

How to find the names for those packages to uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html):

```
pkgnames [prefix]
   This command prints the name of each package APT knows. The
   optional argument is a prefix match to filter the name list.
   [...]

   Note that a package which APT knows of is not necessarily available
   to download, installable or installed, e.g. virtual packages are
   also listed in the generated list.
```

If you want look for installed packages, one way is to use [`apt list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html):

```
list (work-in-progress)
   list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can
   display a list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports
   glob(7) patterns for matching package names as well as options to
   list installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or all
   available (--all-versions) versions.
```

So:

```
apt list --installed 'virtualbox*'
```